# What does it mean "to be $\delta_0-$measurable"?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ a set and $\delta_0:\mathcal P(X)\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $$\delta_0(A)=\begin{cases}1&0\in A\\ 0&sinon\end{cases}\quad A\subset X.$$

We recall that $\delta_0$ is a measure called "Dirac measure".

Let $f:X\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ a function. What does mean "$f$ is a $\delta_0-$ measurable function" ?

---

**Attempt :** Normaly, for function $$f:(X,\mathcal M,\mu)\longrightarrow (Y,\mathcal N,\nu),$$
$f$ is measurable if $$f^{-1}(N)\in \mathcal M$$
for all $N\in\mathcal N$. The problem is that in my question no $\sigma -$algebra are definite in any set (and I suppose that I have to find such $\sigma -$algebra).

---

**Conclusion :** I suspect that the tribute on $X$ is $\mathcal P(X)$ (the poxer set of $X$), and it's measurable if $$f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal P(X),$$
for all $B$ borealian. But with such definition, all function are $\delta_0$ measurable... so may be it's not correct ?

Comment: "$\delta_0$-measurable" doesn't make any sense to me. Besides, note that the English translation of "tribu" is not "tribute" but $\sigma$-algebra (or $\sigma$-field).

Comment: @GabrielRomon: Thank you. Why $\delta_0$-measurable has no meaning ? Of course it make sense (I often see for a measure $\mu$ that a set or a function is $\mu$ measurable...)

Comment: There is the Caratheodory construction of a $\sigma$-algebra from an outer measure, of which the dirac mass is, since a measure is an outer measure. This construction I believe gets you the power set. From a quick google: http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/measch5.pdf but if you didn't know this already and this is homework then I doubt this is what you were supposed to do